# Duplications in an unordered set

Tags: python, set

How do I account for duplication? Notice I have 4 elements in filtered_backup_config and only 3 elements in rendered_config. However, I have an addition 'testing' element in filtered_backup_config. When it compares with rendered_config, it thinks that 'testing' already exist, therefore minus_commands shows empty. Ideal output should display minus_commands = ['testing'].

```
>>> filtered_backup_config = ['hello','world','testing','testing']
>>> rendered_config = ['hello','testing','world']
>>> filtered_set = set(filtered_backup_config)
>>> rendered_set = set(rendered_config)
>>> minus_commands = [x for x in filtered_backup_config if x not in rendered_set]
>>> plus_commands = [x for x in rendered_config if x not in filtered_set]
>>> print minus_commands
[]
>>> print plus_commands
[]
>>>
```

Comment: A set contains unique entries, you can't have duplicates, so why are you using a `set`?

Comment: Once it's converted to a set, there *are* no duplicates. To contain duplicates, it would have to be a bag, not a set. (Python doesn't have bags as such, but there's discussion of them in https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/collections.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> filtered_backup_config = ['hello','world','testing','testing']
>>> rendered_config = ['hello','testing','world']
>>> filtered_set = Counter(filtered_backup_config)
>>> rendered_set = Counter(rendered_config)
>>> minus_commands = filtered_set - rendered_set
>>> print minus_commands
Counter({'testing': 1})
>>> print list(minus_commands.elements())
['testing']
```

**UPD: Preserving the order**

```
def filter_existing(lst, counter):
    counter = Counter(counter)  # make a copy to avoid modifying the passed-in counter
    result = []

    for item in lst:
        if counter[item] > 0:
            counter[item] -= 1
        else:
            result.append(item)

    return result


filtered_backup_config = ['hello', 'world', 'testing', 'testing']
rendered_config = ['hello', 'testing', 'world']
rendered_set = Counter(rendered_config)

print filter_existing(filtered_backup_config, rendered_set)
```